# Google Maps API for Jersey/Guernsey?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

My company is using the Google Maps API to power an installer locator for our product. All has been going fine up until now, when I've added installers on the Channel Islands (UK). Is there any way I can get the Google Maps API to recognize these locations for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't! Geolocation in the channel islands (as provided by google) is very patchy. It doesn't seem to recognize postcodes, for instance.

My company is based on Jersey. On our site, we geolocate a user, then place a marker on the map as to where we think they are. We set this marker to 'draggable', and allow the user to drag the marker to their location if its inaccurate. You can get info on how precisely you have located someone from the API - if its not good enough, you can give extra prompts to tell the user to locate themselves.

This isn't an ideal solution, but its important to have - geolocation services do not work accurately everywhere in the world.

Comment: Ah. Damn. Lol. Okay, what I've had to do is use a service to manually geocode my addresses. I've input those into my database, but Google won't display them on my map using my lat/long values. The odd thing is, one address is working (on my stockist locator), but I tried using that working stockist's details on my installer locator and it can't find it... any suggestions? :-(

Comment: @Anonymous- It's hard to say unless you post code. The code for displaying markers is very simple - a common problem is to have lat/lng wrong way round. You should probably start another question as this is a different problem to the Channel Islands geocoding one.

Comment: The code for both my stockist and installer locators are identical (the same script, with a 'type' parameter determining which table to query), so I don't think there is an error with values being the wrong way around or anything like that since the rest of the queries work as they should. However, you're right - I'll start a new question if I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Channel Islands are editable in Google Mapmaker, which means you can fix most geocoding problems if you happen to know the right answer.  Not all fixes will go live immediately, but they will eventually.